# JQuery function is working on Dev console, but not in load page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting crazy because all was going so good, but now I don't understand why but a simply JQuery function is not working on webpage code when is loaded and when I put the code on the Developer Console is working perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
$('.changinstate').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Just try putting your function inside: `$(function(){$('.changinstate').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
});});`

Comment: Have you wrapped the code into a document.ready listener like basically all jquery? Is your script maybe in the head of your html? The problem is most likely that you're trying to query the DOM before it is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you test with :

`$(document).on('change', '.changinstate', function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log(id);
 });`

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach event when DOM loaded.

```
$(function(){
  $('.changinstate').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
  });
});
```